# Javascript image loading slow on ipad

Tags: javascript, performance, ipad, kineticjs

I am drawing many frames on a canvas using KineticJs library.
I am creating a new javascript Image object with the relevant image source for every frame and setting the new image on the canvas after the image loaded.

I see that it takes about 22ms on chrome and about 600ms on ipad safari ... that's a big difference, has anyone experienced such a behavior and does anyone have any insight on how we can overcome this issue? For example maybe I can force the ipad to use its gpu.

Any response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How large are the images? What are your canvas dimensions? On iPad, a canvas larger than 1024x768 noticeably slows down rendering.

Comment: i figured out that large amount of the loading time is due to javascript single thread context switch and by filtering some unnecessary mouse move actions i managed to lower this loading time, but still the difference between the pc and ipad are huge.\

Comment: most of the ipad screen is the canvas and i am drawing high quality images that i get from the server in base64 format. I am thinking if web worker can help me in some way in this scenario, but i understood that i can not create Image object inside a web worker... hmm, any advice ...

Comment: Are you modifying the image before you put it on the canvas? The only thing a web worker can help with in a situation like this is sending `imageData` and manipulating the pixels. You may just have to see if you can get away with using slightly less high quality images. You can also try using a buffer canvas first, though I don't actually have any stats on if that's going to help with just changing the images.

Answer (score 0):

[This page says that iPad cuts off loading images at 6.5mb](http://roblaplaca.com/blog/2010/05/05/ipad-safari-image-limit-workaround/).  I'm not sure if this is still true but I've definitely noticed throttling before 6.5 mb.

Since I'm using a photo scroller, what I've done is load the image names in a hidden html field and then load the next image in a hidden image tag 2.5 seconds before the scroller displays the next image.  Of course, you could also load the image names in a JavaScript array.  I can provide code snippet if still interested...